# How to create a render layer in blender python

Tags: render-layers

In Blender's 'Render Layers' tab in its 'Scene' section there is a list of render layers. **I wish to know how I can create a new render layer and customise that layer using a script.**

For example, to create a render layer called "Characters" that only renders scene layer number 1 (ignore mask layers for now).

Answer (score 3):

**Create a new render layer with [`Scene.render.layers.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.RenderLayers.html#bpy.types.RenderLayers.new)**

As a rule of thumb, I always use an  API method such as  `new_render_layer = scene.render.layers.new(name)` in preference to the operator, in this case `bpy.ops.scene.render_layer_add()`.

Test code, creates a new render layer named "Characters". Makes it the active render layer. Sets only  scene layer 0 (the first) as included, turns off zmask, and, just for fun,  makes true for every odd zmask layer.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

new_rl = scene.render.layers.new("Characters")
# make active
scene.render.layers.active = new_rl
# set only layer 0 true 
new_rl.layers = [not i for i in range(20)]
# don't use z mask
new_rl.use_zmask = False
# every odd zmask layer
new_rl.layers_zmask = [not i % 2 for i in range(20)]
```

See [`RenderLayer`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.RenderLayers.html#module-bpy.types) docs for more render layer properties to set.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. The output window only ever shows the operator class commands.