# creating more than 20 render layers and connect them to different scenes

Tags: scripting, render-layers, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to render an animation simultaneously from 32 points of view and integrate the result in a composed animation.

I followed this answer:
[How to create a render layer in blender python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105130/how-to-create-a-render-layer-in-blender-python)

and this one:
[How to combine renders from multiple cameras](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23154/how-to-combine-renders-from-multiple-cameras)

However using:

```
basescene=bpy.context.screen.scene
for i in Hs:
 for j in Ws:
   bpy.context.screen.scene=basescene
   bpy.ops.scene.new(type='LINK_OBJECTS')       
   newscene=bpy.context.screen.scene
   newscene.name='scene_h_'+ str(i)+'_w_'+str(j)
   new_render_layer =  scene.render.layers.new('rl_h_'+ str(i)+'_w_'+str(j)) 
   newscene.render.layers.active=new_render_layer
```

Each scene render.layers.active is equal to:

```
 bpy.data.scenes['scene_h_0_w_4'].render.layers["RenderLayer"]
```

Or in other words, whatever scene is selected the following is true:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.layers.active.name == "RenderLayer"
```

Also the scenes would always miss only the last render layer created

```
 e.g.   rl_h_0_w_4 not in scene_h_0_w_4 but scene_h_0_w_4 in scene_h_0_w_5
```

How can I associate each scene to a different render layer and compose them in the final scene?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/rendering-a-stereoscopic-image-in-blender-2-77/

Comment: if you ffind out, let me know because thats seems pretty useful.

Comment: @eromod I found the error...
This line 
    
    new_render_layer =  scene.render.layers.new('rl_h_'+ str(i)+'_w_'+str(j))
has a typo. Should be

new_render_layer =  newscene.render.layers.new('rl_h_'+ str(i)+'_w_'+str(j))

Answer (score 1):

Actually there was a typo.
The following script creates a new scene and a new render layer making it the active one for that scene

```
for j in range(N_PERSP_x):
   bpy.context.screen.scene=basescene
   bpy.ops.scene.new(type='LINK_OBJECTS')       
   newscene=bpy.context.screen.scene
   bpy.context.screen.scene.name='scene_h_'+ str(j)+'_w_'+str(j)
   new_render_layer =  newscene.render.layers.new('rl_h_'+ str(j)+'_w_'+str(j))        
   newscene.render.layers.active = new_render_layer
```

You can check the results with:

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
   print(scene.name,scene.render.layers.active.name)
```